# how to create mp3 player in apache cordova visual studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple mp3 player android app using apache cordova in visual studio 2015,
When I run it in browser it's working but in mobile not working or not playing.

Here is the code only java script.
mp3 files inside wwww folder together with index.html.

```
function PlaySound(path)
{                  
    var e = document.getElementById("txt_alarmtune");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    path = strUser;
    audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', path);
    audioElement.play();
}

function stopVid() {
    audioElement.pause();
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.pause();
}
```

Comment: set some breakpoints in the javascript and step thru it on the emulator or device. You might find that one or more of the lines aren't getting ran/set like they do with a browser.  For instance, what's the path being evaluated to, and is that path truly on the device.

Comment: Also please post the head section of your index.html so we can see the Content Security Policy meta tag, any errors showing up in the remote inspector in Chrome or Safari when you run the device in Cordova, and your code for handling the "deviceready" event.  We may then be better positioned to help.

Comment: here is the header of the index.html.                                                                                             <head>        
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
       
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>ggApps</title>
    </head>.   And thanks for responds brothers....